# If then statement not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an if then statement to create a loop for a slideshow the slides working without the if then statement but wont loop. With statement it just doesn't work. here is the code

```
var $num = null;
$num = parseInt(0, 10);
$("document").ready(function onReady() {
    If($num = 6) {
        $num = parseInt(0, 10);
        $num = parseInt($num, 10) + 1;
        var final = "#img" + $num;
        $(final).fadeTo(3000, 1, function() {
            $(final).fadeTo(3000, 0, onReady);
        });
    }
    Else {
        $num = parseInt($num, 10) + 1;
        var final = "#img" + $num;
        $(final).fadeTo(3000, 1, function() {
            $(final).fadeTo(3000, 0, onReady);
        });
    }

});​
```

Comment: You might want to format your code so it's more readable. Have you tried using an equals operator in your if statements? ie: if (num == 1)

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript is case sensitive.  `if/else`, not `If/Else`. And comparisons are done with `==`.  You mistakenly assign `6` to `$num`  by doing `if ($num = 6)` when you intend to check `($num == 6)`.

```
// No need for this:
// $num = parseInt(0,10);
// Just initialize to zero
var $num = 0;
// However, since you initialized it, it will _never_ be 6 on page load as you test for...
// So maybe you don't actually want this...    

// Fix the $(document).ready()  
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Never going to be 6 since you initialized to zero...
   if ($num == 6 ){
        $num = parseInt(0,10);
        $num = parseInt($num,10) + 1;
            var final = "#img" + $num;
            $(final).fadeTo(3000,1, function() {$(final).fadeTo(3000,0, onReady);});
    }
    else{
        $num = parseInt($num,10) + 1;
        var final = "#img" + $num;
        $(final).fadeTo(3000,1, function() {$(final).fadeTo(3000,0, onReady);});
    }
});
```

Get used to using your web browser's error console.  Firefox 11 has one built in, or Firebug is an excellent extension. Chrome/Safari have developer tools, and IE press F12 for the console.  The errors will be reported on the console.

#### Update:

On a second reading, perhaps you were actually trying to define `onReady` as a function and pass it to `$(document).ready()`. In that case, this is the appropriate method.

```
// If this is the correct intent, then it _does_ make sense to initialize $num 
// since it will be modified when onReady is called
var $num = 0;

// Define the onReady function
function onReady() {
   // Never going to be 6 since you initialized to zero...
   if ($num == 6 ){
        $num = parseInt(0,10);
        $num = parseInt($num,10) + 1;
            var final = "#img" + $num;
            $(final).fadeTo(3000,1, function() {$(final).fadeTo(3000,0, onReady);});
    }
    else{
        $num = parseInt($num,10) + 1;
        var final = "#img" + $num;
        $(final).fadeTo(3000,1, function() {$(final).fadeTo(3000,0, onReady);});
    }
}
// Pass the defined function to ready()
$(document).ready(onReady);
```

Comment: Also change `$("document").ready(function onReady() {` to

`$("document").ready(function() {`

Comment: @KyleMacey I don't think it's trolling - there are tons of errors here.

Comment: @Michael, no, I know, he just edited the same comment like 5 times pointing out random stuff not directly related to the OQ

Comment: Kyle, must have been a technical issue. Also, it is quite related to the issue as the entire could block was not firing due to that error. Thanks for the constructive criticism though.